# Clone subobject/face without moving

Tags: copy, clone, flip, 3dsmax

I've spent about 20 minutes searching for this to no avail. All I want to do is create a double sided face for a shop sign for example. 
[image]

I create a face that sticks out from the building, and I obviously want it double-sided, so I want to simply clone the face and flip the normal.

I know I can do this holding shift and translating the face, but then I have to move it back. I know that you can do this for an object in the edit menu, just selecting clone object, but it doesn't seem to work for sub-objects (ie., faces).

Also, when I searched for how to make a face double-sided, most suggestions were to change the renderer settings to change the face culling, or to apply a double-sided material. But, neither of these methods actually create a new face, do they? For example if I were to export it to my OpenGL project, exporting it wouldn't create the extra face vertices, would it?

Thank you.

Edit: I've been thinking, I know there are many ways to achieve this, I just thought I could detach the face to its own object, clone it in its place, flip the normal, and then attach the two objects to the original again, but the workflow is supposed to be easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've been playing around a bit, and found out that you can
1: Select the face.
2: Click Detach.
3: Select Detach As Clone.
4: Select Detach As Element if you want it to stay in the same object.